# Zend_XmlRpc :Failed to parse response error

Tags: xml-rpc, zend-xmlrpc

Am trying to get a simple hello world XMLRPC server setup to work.However I get this **Failed to parse response error** error when I run the test URL 
**http://localhost/client/index/** on my browser

In my Rpc Controller that handles all my XMLRPC calls

```
class RpcController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }

    public function xmlrpcAction()
    {
        $server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Server();
        $server->setClass('Service_Rpctest','test');
        $server->handle();
    }
}
```

In my client Controller that calls the XMLRPC Server

```
class ClientController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
      $clientrpc = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://localhost/rpc/xmlrpc/');
      //Render Output to the view   
      $this->view->rpcvalue = $clientrpc->call('test.sayHello');
    }
}
```

In my Service_Rpctest function

```
<?php
class Service_Rpctest
{
    /**
    * Return the Hello String
    * 
    * @return string
    */  
    public function sayHello()
    {
        $value = 'Hello';
        return $value;
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you send xml output :

```
echo $server->handle();
```